# Cloud SQL Private IP Error: Set Service Consumer Management service account as owner role on VPC host project

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to assign a private IP to a Cloud SQL instance and it's returning the error message "set Service Consumer Management service account as owner role on VPC host project".

I get the same error if I navigate to VPC Network -> default -> Private Service Connection -> Private Connections to services -> Create Connection.

I added service-[PROJECT_NUMBER]@service-consumer-management.iam.gserviceaccount.com as an Owner to the IAM policy but it's not helping.  Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

After about 12 hours it seems to be working now.  I think the key was adding service-[PROJECT_NUMBER]@service-consumer-management.iam.gserviceaccount.com as an Owner to the IAM policy.